# 'Euclidean Multitorus' and the Riesz-Kakutani Representation Thorem in Lax's Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request

In the appendix part A, Lax proves the following result:

If $Q$ is a $\textbf{compact}$ Hausdorff Space, and $C(Q)$ denotes the class of continuous functions, then if $l \in C(Q)$ is a positive linear functional, there exists a 'measure' $m$ such that for any $c \in C(Q)$ we have:

\begin{align*}
l(c) = \int c \ dm
\end{align*}
He then says in the last part, if we take $l$ to be the usual Riemann Integral, and $Q$ to be the 'Euclidean Multitorus', we recover the Lebesgue stuff.

Q1: Surprisingly, searching 'Euclidean multitorus' online lead nowhere, I couldn't find any such compact space, what is this object?(I have very nominal topology knowledge)

Q2: My main question is that how is it possible to recover the Lebesgue measure for the full $\mathbb{R}^n$ from a compact space? Other places start with a locally compact hausdorff space $X$ and $C_c(X)$ which makes it easier to see the correspondence, however, the proofs here are much simpler and easier since there is one 'unital' element for the measure($u(q)=1$ for any $q \in Q$; $m(S) \leq l(u)$)) which makes estimation easier.

Comment: I guess he meant $Q = [0,1]^n$. From the Lebesgue measure on this $Q$ can you derive the Lebesgue measure on arbitrary rectangles? Then you can define the Lebesgue measure for bounded sets and take some kind of limit. Alternatively you could also use the Caratheodory extension theorem.

Comment: @blamethelag How would we define measurable sets? Also wouldn't using the Caratheodory extension theorem kind of defeat the idea behind getting the Lebesgue Measure as a consequence of this theorem?

Comment: In the first case I would take the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. In the second one I would use the "outer measure" definition of measurable set. I agree with you that the using Caratheodory extension theorem annihilate the interest of building the Lebesgue measure without its standard construction, which is essentially using the Carathéodory extension theorem (my bad!).